# Ant design editable Paragraph value become null when onChange is triggered

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd, paragraph, typography

```
import {Typography} from 'antd'
const {Paragraph} = Typography

const [value, setValue] = useState("This is initial value");
const onChangeEdit = editVal => {
    setValue(editVal);
};

<Paragraph editable={{ onChange: onChangeEdit }}> {value} </Paragraph>
```

I have issue with above code.

[image]

Initially, the Paragraph has "This is intial value" as a intital value. Hence, if I start editing, it should have "This is intial value" as a intial value.

But whenever I click the edit icon, the input box become empty instead of having inital value.

What's the solution to correct this issue?

Comment: it seems the code was fine. For better debugging you can place the full code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: hey @Chanandrei, thanks for your comment, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bird-urkwc?file=/src/App.js) is sample code

Comment: FYI, [here](https://ant.design/components/typography/) is official doc for Typography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue! First, include the css of antd on index.js

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```

then remove the spaces inside the `<Paragraph>` component, it should be:

```
<Paragraph editable={{ onChange: onChange }}>{value}</Paragraph>
```

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-pond-ttv84?file=/src/App.js:363-427) is the working link